# LoadLibrary fails only when running from eclipse & tomcat

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, tomcat, loadlibrary

UnsatisfiedLinkError when trying to load Lingo library, on Linux 64 bit, in Java using

```
static{
    System.loadLibrary("lingojni64"); 
     }
```

After setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/utcn11/lingo14/bin/linux64
```

- when running from command line works fine;
- when running from eclipse gives:
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lingojni64 in java.library.path

Already tried setting

```
System.setProperty("java.library.path", "/home/utcn11/lingo14/bin/linux64");
```

But same error occurs

- when running from eclipse after setting the
  -Djava.library.path="/home/utcn11/lingo14/bin/linux64"
  The following error occurs:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/utcn11/lingo14/bin/linux64/liblingojni64.so.14.0: liblingo64.so.14: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

```
ls -l /home/utcn11/lingo14/bin/linux64

total 41084

lrwxrwxrwx 1 utcn11 utcn11       16 Sep 29 16:36 liblingo64.so -> liblingo64.so.14

lrwxrwxrwx 1 utcn11 utcn11       18 Sep 29 16:36 liblingo64.so.14 -> liblingo64.so.14.0

-rwxr-xr-x 1 utcn11 utcn11  2911124 Oct 15  2013 liblingo64.so.14.0

lrwxrwxrwx 1 utcn11 utcn11       19 Sep 29 16:36 liblingojni64.so -> liblingojni64.so.14

lrwxrwxrwx 1 utcn11 utcn11       21 Sep 29 16:36 liblingojni64.so.14 -> liblingojni64.so.14.0

-rwxr-xr-x 1 utcn11 utcn11    28809 Aug 22  2013 liblingojni64.so.14.0
```

- same error occurs when running the webapp in tomcat

Comment: Are you using the same x64 JVM in both Eclipse and the command line ?

Comment: Where are you setting -Djava.library.path value ? In Program arguments (or) VM arguments. Note that it has to go as a part of VM arguments.

Comment: I set it in the VM arguments

Answer (score 1):

If run the project from Eclipse you can follow the next steps:

1. Right click on the project.
2. Go to **Run as -> Run Configurations...**
3. Go to the **Environment** tab.
4. Click on **New** to create a new environment variable.
5. Enter the name of the variable (`LD_LIBARY_PATH`) and its path.
6. Click **OK**, then **Apply**.